# authentication to oauth fails on IIS

Tags: .net, iis, deployment, oauth

I use oauth authentication to add contacts to google Contacts api
when I deploy to `iis` I get this error:

> Server Error in '/' Application. Access is denied Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is
>   denied

Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied]
   System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) +604
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) +60
   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.<ReceiveCodeAsync>d__16.MoveNext() +258

[NotSupportedException: Failed to launch browser with "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&response_type=code&client_id=347204707806-a44e1b5q57mqr0bkvic9gd03ms52nk0c.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A54450%2Fauthorize%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth2%2Fcontacts%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fm8%2Ffeeds" for authorization. See inner exception for details.]
   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.<ReceiveCodeAsync>d__16.MoveNext() +832
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60
   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.<AuthorizeAsync>d__8.MoveNext() +701
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60
   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.<AuthorizeAsync>d__4.MoveNext() +572
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +60
   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.<AuthorizeAsync>d__1.MoveNext() +426

 string clientId = xxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";
            string clientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

        string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts" };     // view your basic profile info.

        // Use the current Google .net client library to get the Oauth2 stuff.
        UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets { ClientId = clientId, ClientSecret = clientSecret }
                                                                                     , scopes
                                                                                     , "teste"
                                                                            , CancellationToken.None
                                                                                     , new FileDataStore(Server.MapPath("/") + "Datastore", true)).Result;
        try
        {
            // Translate the Oauth permissions to something the old client libray can read
            OAuth2Parameters parameters = new OAuth2Parameters();
            parameters.AccessToken = credential.Token.AccessToken;
            parameters.RefreshToken = credential.Token.RefreshToken;



            RequestSettings settings = new RequestSettings("contacts-241820", parameters);
            ContactsRequest cr = new ContactsRequest(settings);
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)

                CreateContact(cr);
```

Comment: what is the content of your web.config? there can be a setting related to the Exception you have.

Comment: on visual studio 2017 and IISExpress runs fine

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.2.1" newVersion="4.0.2.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.4.0" newVersion="5.2.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" />
      <add name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" type="Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule, Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation" preCondition="integratedMode,managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looking at your code, looks like the code you are running is based on .NET Core, and I think you have to be sure that for running the app on IIS, you need to be sure that you have IIS ANCM installed.

See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: it is not .net core it is mvc .net 4.6

Comment: Then please submit the content of your web.config, as I have asked before.

Comment: i posted above the web.config